# Decide where to store a set of fields (name and data type) for creating/editing records in the database

Tags: reactjs

It is necessary to decide where to store a set of fields (name and data type) for creating/editing records in the database.

[image: Admin Panel]

my project is created using several technologies: react, redux-toolkit (createSlice), postgres, laravel.

some code of that part:

```js
return editMode
        // Окно создания и редактирования
        ? <Layout direction={"column"} className="edit_mode">
                <ShowEditInfo/>
                <TextField
                    label="Заголовок"
                    name={"title"}
                    // value={editingProd.title}
                    // onChange={handlePostFields}
                />
                <TextField
                    label="Описание"
                    name={"body"}
                    type={"textarea"}
                    rows={3}
                    cols={50}
                    // value={editingProd.body}
                    // onChange={handlePostFields}
                />
                <Button
                    label={"Опубликовать"}
                    disabled={disTempPost}
                    onClick={onUpdateButton}
                />
            </Layout>
        // Админ
        : <Layout direction={"column"} className={"admin_table"}>
            <Table
                zebraStriped="odd"
                // activeRow={{id: selectedItem}}
                onCellClick={onCellClick}
                rows={products}
                columns={columns}
                borderBetweenColumns
                borderBetweenRows
                emptyRowsPlaceholder={onEmptyTable}
            />
            <TableFooter
                products={products}
                table={table}
                CountAmountOfPosts={CountAmountOfPosts}
                isDisableButton={isDisableButton}
                loading={loading}
                limit={limit}
                handleSelect={handleSelect}
            />
        </Layout>
```

1. Store them raw in react (FOR EACH TAB), in which case this set will be loaded (extra traffic) even if the user is not an admin.
   benefits are easier.
   cons - does not follow the changes that have occurred on the server, for example, a new field has been added - it will not be on the front right away (((.
2. Store on the server and apply on the front when the user is authorized as an admin. difficulty: medium
   advantages - changes are not embedded on the front, the front will serve for a long time without changing files.
   Cons - changes on the server do not follow changes in the database, adding a new field does not entail changing the data set.
3. Make an adaptive super duper impossible algorithm where all fields will be described in the database as a set of type and value.
   advantages: any changes will carry changes on the front and filling in new required fields will not cause an error.
   cons - difficult, costly from the economic part of software development, not cost-effective for small projects. Temporary pit, it will just take all the time to do this, but he could do something else.
4. Don't care - add to the list of upgrade paths.
   advantages: there will be an illusion that the project is not finished, because it is being actively developed.
   cons: it will seem that the programmer doesn't know. Didn't do what goes without saying necessary.

Comment: The database holds the data in a table which has 'fields' of different 'types' eg a Date or a Text or a Boolean, integer... value.    The layout is a template for presenting the information in the database in a human readable format. The 'fields' in the layout should correlate to the same data Type to the field that is in the database table you're accessing.

Comment: @Winston the information is already known. I need some solution or idea to automate the creating and updating fields compariing it with languages JS, PHP and PostgreSQL.
for example: object ~ json